# How to stop JSContext evaluating in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I need to interrupt `[context evaluateScript:js]` while it's running, I can't find a way in the document and Google. Can anyone help?

Comment: A naive approach, I guess, that you can call some Objective-C method from JavaScript that will notify JS code (return bool value) that it should stop execution. And periodically invoke this method and abort execution from JS.

Comment: @BorysVerebskyi the evaluateScript method runs the js like blind until the script stops by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this to work using `JavaScriptCore`. I tried:

- Wrapping the code in a `DispatchWorkItem` and calling `cancel()`
- Wrapping the code in an `Operation` and trying to cancel it as well as `nil`'ing the `OperationQueue` (that actually causes an app to crash).
- Using the C APIs in `JavaScriptCore` as well as the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to manually manage memory.

None of those work.

What **did work** was to use a `WKWebView` and as soon as it is `nil`'ed, the `evaluateJavaScript` function calls its completion handler. I posted an example [here](https://github.com/juanjo-ramos/StopJavaScript/blob/master/StopJavaScript/StopJavaScript/JavaScript%20Engines/WKWebViewJSCore.swift).

For anyone trying that, bear in mind that is undocumented behaviour so it may change in any upcoming iOS version.

Comment: If needs more context results to be returned. Set WKScriptMessageHandler to WKUserContentController for the webView and remove the handler when deinit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `JSContext`'s `evaluateJavaScript` method. Due to no cancel method on the context so you can not stop it. And iOS does not like macOS could use XPC so no way to stop the external running environment.

However, there is a workaround about it. Just think the `JSContext` likes a browser. The scripts are flying on the way. How to stop it by an external event. The most convenient way is construct yourself's runloop. Make tasks small and put it in the queue.

### Custom runloop

I export one native Timer to call javascript handler on downloadWithHandler methold every several seconds and set `isCancelled` to true at some point. The runloop will be stopped and JSContext eval reaches the end of the whole script and return.

native:

```swift
    let script = viewModel.string
    let context = EAJSContext()!
    // context will be dealloc after finish if not retain here.
    // not retain it to debugging
    // viewModel.context = context 

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // inject helper metholds 
        JavaScriptCoreHelper().config(context: context)

        // export download(handler:) method
        Emulator.configure(context: context)

        let result = context.evaluateScript(script)
        print("context return result: \(result)")
    }
```

scripts:

```js
var emulator = Emulator.create();

var taskIsFinish = false;

const promiseA = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    emulator.downloadWithHandler( (response) => {
        // native pass dictionary
        var isFinish = response["isFinish"];
        var isCancelled = response["isCancelled"];
        var date = response["date"];

        console.log("isFinish: " + isFinish);
        console.log("isCancelled: " + isCancelled);
        console.log("date: " + date);

        if (isFinish || isCancelled) {
            resolve(date);
        }
    });
});

promiseA
.then( (val) => {
    console.log("asynchronous logging has val: " + val)
    taskIsFinish = true
})

while(!taskIsFinish) {
    // long task in queue
    sleep(1);
    console.log('long task');
}
```

output:

```
2020-05-10 04:07:06.766592+0800 …[34354:2831281] [interaction] … runToolbarItemPressed(_:): run triggerd
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: false
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:06 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: false
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:06 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: long task
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: false
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:07 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: long task
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: false
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:08 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: long task
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: false
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:10 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: long task
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: false
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:11 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: long task
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: true
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:12 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: asynchronous logging has val: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:12 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: long task
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: true
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:13 GMT+0800 (CST)
context return result: Optional(undefined)
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: true
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:13 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log: isFinish: false
console.log: isCancelled: true
console.log: date: Sun May 10 2020 04:07:13 GMT+0800 (CST)
2020-05-10 04:07:13.391950+0800 …[34354:2831310] [debug] EAJSContext.swift[16], deinit
```

(The memory could be leaking if the context not deinit after eval finish.)

### Other thinking

Wrapper the context in the native Worker class. And set the flag to make that worker return callback fast with the empty result when task canceled. Do not retain and throw it away.